# Primefaces selectCheckBoxMenu filter="custom" property doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and i want to use selectCheckBoxMenu component. Actually, i handle lots of property of this component, but i have huge list and i am willing to get this list with lazy and this component doesn't include lazy property. Therefore, i decided to filter my list by using filter="custom" and filterFunction property.

Here is my code :

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="personelListesiCheckBoxId"
                                      value="#{gidenKutusuController.secilenKullaniciListesi}"
                                      converter="#{personelConverter}"
                                      label="#{gidenKutusuController.personelLabel}"
                                      filter="true"
                                      filterMatchMode="custom"
                                      filterFunction="customFilter"
                                      panelStyle="width:220px">
                    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" process="@this"
                            onstart="personelGetir();"/>
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                            process="@this"
                            listener="#{gidenKutusuController.listenerPersonelSecildi()}"
                            update="@this"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{gidenKutusuController.personelListesi}" var="personel"
                                   itemLabel="#{personel.adi} #{personel.soyadi}"
                                   itemValue="#{personel}"/>
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                <p:remoteCommand process="@this"
                                 action="#{gidenKutusuController.listenerPersonelSecildi()}"
                                 name="personelGetir"
                                 update=":form:personelListesiCheckBoxId"/>
                <p:remoteCommand process="@this"
                                 action="#{gidenKutusuController.listenerPersonelListesiLazyGetirByFilter()}"
                                 name="personelListesiniGetirByFilter"
                                 update="@this"/>
```

and this java script code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function customFilter(itemLabel, filterValue) {
        personelListesiniGetirByFilter({fv: filterValue});
    }
</script>
```

I want to do that when the user type into filter, i get that value and query database with that value and get list and set the list to the selectCheckBoxMenu component.To do that, 
i use filterMatchMode="custom" and filterFunction="customFilter" in order to get the typed value, then normally when the user typed, customFilter java script function must be called , it is not working.

I don't know how to solve the problem. Please help me.

Here is the primefaces 3.5 guide

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{bean.selectedOptions}" label="Movies"
             filterMatchMode="custom" filterFunction="customFilter">
             <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>


function customFilter(itemLabel, filterValue) {
     //return true to accept and false to reject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code does not work is that the filterFunction expects a function implemented in your bean:  nameOfYourCustomFunction(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale). For example, take a look at how PrimeFaces "ContainsFilterConstraint.java" Class is implemented. Also, look at my answer in this question, in order to get your selectCheckboxMenu Filter to actually work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34383835/4145964