# Using custom filter in selectCheckboxMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have 2 elements in a form:

**-selectCheckboxMenu**

**-selectOneMenu**

In these two elements I have:

**-filter="true"**

**-filterMatchMode="custom"**

**-filterFunction="customFilter"**

For **selectCheckboxMenu** is working correctly, but for **selectCheckboxMenu** isn´t.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273019/primefaces-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-custom-property-doesnt-work) on stackoverflow, but from the documentation I can read:

"When filtering is enabled with setting filter on, an input field is rendered at overlay header and on keyup event filtering is executed on client side using filterMatchMode. Default modes of filterMatchMode are startsWith, contains, endsWith and **custom**. **Custom mode requires a javascript function to do the filtering."**

```html
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{bean.selectedOptions}" label="Movies"
  filterMatchMode="custom" filterFunction="customFilter">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>

function customFilter(itemLabel, filterValue) {
//return true to accept and false to reject
 }
```

So, for **selectCheckboxMenu** should be working, but it seems **selectCheckboxMenu** is not using the **customFilter** javascript function.

How can I make it work? am I missing something?

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745238/primefaces-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-doesnt-work-while-selectonemenu-well-insid/34383835#34383835) answer, but I didn´t have luck with that. That´s why I´m creating another question.

Comment: I always use a lazyDataModel for filtering. More control and less complex for complex cases

Comment: @Kukeltje in this case I should put options as lazyDataModel?
and how can I call to refresh this lazyDataModel? I tried with Ajax, but the events for key are not supported in this case.

Comment: No, the filtering itself. Check the showcase example